# Удаление элемента JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.input').val() == "") {
    alert('Введите дело');
    return
  }
  $('.todo').append(`<li>${$('.input').val()}
      <button class="delete">&#10006</button></li>`);
  $('.input').val("");
})

$(".delete").on('click', function() {
  let parent = $(this).parent();
  parent.remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="spisok">
  <div class="spisok__text">ToDo List</div>
  <input class="input" type="text">
  <button>ADD</button>
  <ul class="todo">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Почему при нажатии на кнопку крестик, которая создаётся с классом .delete тег li не удаляется[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

1. потому что вы обращаетесь к элементу, которого ещё нет на странице. Здесь нужно воспользоватся [делегированием событий](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation)
   И код поменять немного:

```js
$(document).on('click',".delete", function(){
        let parent = $(this).parent();
        parent.remove();
    })
```

2. НИКОГДА, не делайте селектором html элемент. Это может вам очень больно аукнутся, если на странице появится 2й такой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет работать:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    if ( $('.input').val() == "" ) {
        alert('Введите дело');
        return
    }
    $('.todo').append(`<li>${$('.input').val()}
        <button class="delete">&#10006</button></li>`);
    $('.input').val("");
});



$(document).on('click', function(e){
    let clickedEl = e.target;
    if ($(clickedEl).hasClass('delete')) {
      $(clickedEl).parent().remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="spisok">
      
      <div class="spisok__text">ToDo List</div>
      
       <input class="input" type="text"> 
      
       <button>ADD</button>
      
      
     

      <ul class="todo">
       
      </ul>
     </div>

     



     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="alert.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```